# The sides of an obtuse triangle have lengths $x$, $2x+2$ and $2x+3$. Between what values is $x$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry

I attempted to apply the triangle equality here and ended up with the following inequalities:
\begin{align*}
x < 4x + 5 & \implies -\frac{5}{3} < x, \\
2x + 2 < 3x +3 & \implies -1 < x, \\
2x + 3 < 3x +2 & \implies 1 < x.
\end{align*}
Where do I go from here? I feel like I'm missing something silly. This is a problem on a middle school math homework.

Comment: The only one of these conditions that tells you anything informative is the last: $x>1$.

Comment: The "obtuse" condition is the one you haven't analysed. Note that the obtuse angle will be opposite the longest side, and derive an inequality from the cosine formula.

Answer (score 2):

We need to solve the following system:
$$x>1$$ and $$(2x+2)^2+x^2<(2x+3)^2.$$
I got $$1<x<5.$$

Comment: Gotcha thank you so much!!!!

Comment: @Math You are welcome!

Answer (score 2):

A bit of  detail:

1) Sum of $2$ sides of a triangle is greater than $3$rd side:

$x >1$.

2) Cosine rule:

$(2x+3)^2=$

$(2x+2)^2+ x^2 -2(2x+2)x \cos \gamma.$

Obtuse : $\gamma >90°$, then $\cos \gamma <0$.

This implies

$(2x+3)^2  > (2x+2)^2+x^2;$

$0>x^2-4x-5$;

$0>(x+1)(x-5);$

$ -1< x<5$;

Combining 1) and 2): $1<x<5$.

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_cosines

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, refer to the figure:

$\hspace{5cm}$[image: ![enter image description here]

For the triangle $ABC$ to be obtuse, $y$ must be positive. Hence:
$$\begin{cases}(x+y)^2+z^2=(2x+3)^2\\ y^2+z^2=(2x+2)^2\end{cases} \stackrel{(1)-(2)}\Rightarrow y=\frac{4x+5-x^2}{2x}>0 \stackrel{x>0}\Rightarrow \\
x^2-4x-5<0 \Rightarrow -1<x<5.$$
And for the triangle $ABC$ to exist, the triangle inequalities dictate $x>1$ as you found.